# No default option is configured for constraint Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

Hi  I have this Exception : **No default option is configured for constraint Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime**.

In My Controller i have :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{


public function  test2Action()
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $id = 1; // ID du bureau de test que l'on a enregistré précédemment

    $desk = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MytestBundle:Desk')->find($id);
    echo "Le bureau récupéré porte l'ID: ".$desk->getId()." et le titre: ".$desk->getTitle();

    $comment = new DeskComment();
    $comment->setDescrption("Mon premier commentaire: Joli bureau !");
    $comment->setSubmissionIp($this->getRequest()->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    $comment->setCreateAt(new DateTime('now'));
    $comment->setDesk($desk); // On lie le commentaire à notre bureau d'ID 1

    $em->persist($comment); // On persist le commentaire 1

    $comment2 = new DeskComment();
    $comment2->setDescrption("Mon deuxième commentaire: J'adore le bureau ! Bravo !");
    $comment2->setSubmissionIp($this->getRequest()->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    $comment->setCreateAt(new DateTime('now'));
    $comment2->setDesk($desk); // On lie le commentaire à notre bureau d'ID 1

    $em->persist($comment2); // On persist le commentaire 2

    $em->flush(); // On sauvegarde en BDD les deux commentaires

     return $this->render('MytestBundle:Default:test2.html.twig');
}
```

I think the problem is **new DateTime('now')**

Any help !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `\` before DateTime `new \DateTime('now')`. If you are not using the `\`, your DateTime is interpreted as `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime` not the PHP `DateTime`.

You can remove `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime;` after that.

Comment: it works for the first but not for the second date why??

Comment: @user3816170 did you modify the 2 DateTime? You have to remove the `use` statement and add the \ before the two `new DateTime`

Comment: Litz yes i modified the second date!!

Comment: Because you are using $comment->setCreatedAt not $comment2->setCreatedAt.
voilà :)